# Function not saving to structure

Tags: c++, function, structure

Maybe I'm burnt out but I cannot figure out why every time I run this code the getInfo function will not write the cin data to the MovieData structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct MovieData {
    string Title, Director, Year_Released, RunningTime;
};

MovieData film1;
MovieData film2;

void getInfo(MovieData something)
{
    cout << "Please enter...\n";
    cout << "Title: ";
    cin >> something.Title;
    cout << "Director: ";
    cin >> something.Director;
    cout << "Year Released: ";
    cin >> something.Year_Released;
    cout << "Running Time: ";
    cin >> something.RunningTime;
}

void showInfo(MovieData something1)
{
    cout << something1.Title << endl;
    cout << something1.Director << endl;
    cout << something1.Year_Released << endl;
    cout << something1.RunningTime << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}



int main()
{
    getInfo(film1);
    showInfo(film1);
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know whether this is some kind of global/local issue it seems to only work if I manually have every get info line in the main function.

Comment: You never return something from `getInfo` So either make the function return the variable  `something` or call the function `getInfo` by reference instead of by value (i think the latter would be a better solution

Comment: I recommend reading up on "pass by reference" vs "pass by value." Understanding those two fundamental concepts are important. http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/references.html

Comment: @JackV Why do you think pass by reference is a better solution than a return value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change the declaration of getInfo to

```
void getInfo(MovieData& something)
```

(note the added `&`) it should work. The issue is that you are passing `something` by value and you want to pass it by reference.

When you call `getInfo` with your current declaration, the `something` it gets is only a copy of argument you passed in. That copy is modified by the function, but the original object stays the same. By adding changing the type of the parameter to `MovieData&` you are passing the argument by reference, and modifications inside the function will be reflected in the original object.

In general, in `C++` if you need to modify function arguments you should pass them by reference, not value.

Comment: I prefer a function called `getX` to return something.

Answer (score 2):

The reason what you've posted doesn't do what you expect is because you pass `something` by value. Essentially, `film1` is copied into `something`, then you modify that copy, then the copy is destroyed at the end of the function. `film1` is never touched.

You can get around that by passing by reference, as toth mentions, however, if the goal of `getInfo` is to populate a `MovieData`, why not return it instead of modifying your input parameter? It makes the function's signature more intuitive. For example:

```
MovieData getInfo()
{
    MovieData something
    cout << "Please enter...\n";
    cout << "Title: ";
    cin >> something.Title;
    cout << "Director: ";
    cin >> something.Director;
    cout << "Year Released: ";
    cin >> something.Year_Released;
    cout << "Running Time: ";
    cin >> something.RunningTime;

    return something;
}
```

Then in main, you can

```
MovieData film1 = getInfo();
showInfo(film1);
```

This way, no one can pass an already popuplated `MovieData` into your function and have it clobbered.

Comment: I prefer this to the approach of `void getInfo(MovieData&);` however on its own merits it doesn't answer the question (imo, you should explain why OP's code doesn't do what he expects, and then offer the solution)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `MovieData` to `getInfo` by value so you are changing a local copy within the function and the original variable does not see the changes.

You could fix it by taking a reference instead (`MovieData&`) but the more idiomatic C++ way would be to use a return type:

```
MovieData getInfo()
{
    MovieData something;
    cout << "Please enter...\n";
    cout << "Title: ";
    cin >> something.Title;
    cout << "Director: ";
    cin >> something.Director;
    cout << "Year Released: ";
    cin >> something.Year_Released;
    cout << "Running Time: ";
    cin >> something.RunningTime;
    return something;
}
```

Off-topic: It is generally best to avoid global variables like `film1` if you can. In this case you can define the variable within the `main` function:

```
int main() {
    MovieData film = getInfo();
}
```